# Unity add children to blendtree

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, animation

I am trying to make a script that will take in a list of animations and automatically add them to the blend tree. I've had a look at the blend tree API and came up with this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Animations;

public class AnimationSwitcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Motion> animations;
    public Animator animator;




    public BlendTree blendTree;

    public void addMotions()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < animations.Count; i++)
        {
            blendTree.AddChild(animations[i]);
        }
    }
    
}
```

I know that I have to use the animator component, but I can't get a easily readable answer on how I can use it to add the blendtree children. I've tried assigning the blendtree in the editor, but that didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Animations;

public class AnimationSwitcher : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Motion> animations;
    public AnimatorController animator;
    private BlendTree blendTree;

    void Start()
    {
        animator.CreateBlendTreeInController("Active", out blendTree);
        blendTree.AddChild(animations[0]);
    }


    public void addMotions()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < animations.Count; i++)
        {
            blendTree.AddChild(animations[i]);
        }
    }
   
}
```